# Difference between 'Page tab' and 'Application on Facebook'

Tags: facebook

I would like to know what is the difference between those two categories that I have to select when I register the 'application' (this term applies also for the 'Page tab').
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Er, one is an app to be installed as  tab on a Facebook page and the other isn a canvas app accessed at apps.facebook.com/appname - The documentation covers the two types of app pretty clearly:

Canvas apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Page tab apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Thanks. Just for better clarification, a 'Facebook application' creates a Facebook page and plays inside the Facebook frame as does the Page tab inside a frame in www.facebook.com/fbpage. It is at least what I have tested, we can get the same final result but on two different ways.